# Laravel 4 Model validation vs Controller validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It seems like official way to validate models in Laravel 4 is through `Validator` in `Controller`? Can somebody point out why is it so?

Wouldn't it make more sense to implement validation in `Model`?

Comment: I wouldn't say official. It's just an easier way of demonstrating the validator as setting up a decent validation service is a little more involved. There's a bunch of examples out there as well as packages that perform the validation within the model itself or as a separate service. Look into those.

Comment: One advantage to Model validation is that seeding is also validated.

Comment: I _would_ say official as this is the only way suggested by the official documentation. If that's not official, what else would be?

Comment: Agreed, what is official / best practice... if the documentation is not? a reflection of this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I prefer the [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) package for making validation of models as smooth and minimal as possible. To me it makes more sense to have the validation rules in the model as well.

It will return false when `$model->save()` is called and validation fails, then you can get the error messages through `$model->errors()->all()` for example.

Comment: Feels very Laravel'ish to me: Use a package that does all the hard work for you.

Comment: @NiklasModess do you have any suggestions on how I could use both Ardent and another package I'm using that extends Eloquent to allow for a MongoDB ORM? My model extends the model that this other package created.

Comment: @NiklasModess, do you know of any package that would let my models be both Ardent models AND MongoDB models?

Comment: @Ryan, unfortunately no. If you're not willing to write a base model extending the Ardent class and then implementing MongoDB storage in that.

Answer (score 5):

It does make sense to have validation in the models, but this validation should only be there to make sure you don't save any corrupt data.

The `Validator` is in the `Controller` because it's used to handle Input, and generate Output.
If you would do the validation in the `Model` then you either have to return false, and show the user the most random of error messages about invalid data.
You could also return some kine of array containing all the errors that are generated, but that's something a Model shouldn't do.
Or you could throw an Exception, which is something that should be done when a model tries to consume invalid data, but it kills the application, which is not the wanted solution for a form validator.

When doing the form validation in the Controller, you can do everything you want with the error messages, without changing the purpose of a Model.

And in your model you can do a validation to make sure you didn't make a mistake, which will corrupt your database. Because if this happens the application should shut down.

So to put this in a real answer to your question:
Validation in the model makes sense to avoid corrupt data, but if you want to give feedback to the user about invalid input, it should be in the controller.

Comment: I think defining the validation rules in just one place, and not in multiple places (the model, the controller, the front-end form) is the key here. The model is the one common thing in this scenario.

Comment: why "shouldn't" the model contain it's own error messages? if you think of models as wrappers for your DB, when you try to insert invalid data into your DB SQL will give you back an error message, who why not let models do it too?

Answer (score 2):

I wrestled with this for a while and settled on handling most of my validation in a validation service, based something along the lines of [this](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-advanced-validation). I can then have different validation rules based on the context.

As Nico mentions, validation in the model is good to avoid corrupt data, but I prefer thin controllers so I pass the functionality that would sit in controller into the service. This also has the benefit of being able to reuse the validation in different controllers/methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Why I prefer In-Model Validation**: I've worked with both styles and each have pluses and minuses, but I prefer in-model validation. In our current app I don't see in-controller validation as an option, since we're altering our data in so many places (dedicated forms, inline edit, bulk edit, bulk upload, api, etc). I've never really worked with validation services (though they might be an option) but I personally like to keep logic as close to the model as possible, that way I know another developer won't bypass it. I also don't like adding lots of extra files on top of the MVC and basic Libraries folder because it just seems like more you have to think about organizing properly.

**Issues with In-Model Validation**: These are some things you need to consider to make In-Model work well. **SOME OF THESE ARE ALREADY TAKEN INTO CONSIDERATION BY PLUGINS**. I think other frameworks (CakePHP) already deal with these, but Laravel doesn't really.

1. Values that will be validated but not saved to the db (e.g.,
   "accepted_agreement").
2. Many to many or belongs to many
   relationships
3. Setting conditional defaults (not critical but
   might want to think about at the same time)
4. Various form scenarios - sometimes you might need different validation
   depending upon which form submits it. The form reference can be a
   purgeable attribute for validation maybe?
5. How will you get back error messages (all in-model validation plugins handle this for you)
6. Different validation rulesets. Draft creation vs "real" creation. (Most handle this for you)

Ultimately, for simple applications that don't have lots of ways of interacting with the model, I'd say controller validation *may* be simpler, other then that I prefer in-model.